# Extract a graphic from the pdf document

Tags: graphics, pdf

I have a pdf file which contain text, image and text as :

```
text ....
My image
text ...
```

how can i do to print just the image on latex ?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the question. Do you have the tex-file? And do not want to compile the test parts? Then just remove the text in the tex-file. Or just comment it out.

Comment: If all you have is the pdf document you can cut the image from the pdf and save it as a jpg or png to include in your `LaTeX` source with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks but i want to add it directly from pdf, if i cut the image from the pdf and save it as a jpg or png the qualtily is so bad :(

Comment: You may try `pdfpages` insert the page and clip the page just to have the image.

Comment: `man pdfimages`

Comment: You would only need pdfpages if the final image exceeds the usual text width/height. If not, a simple `\includegraphics[trim='left'cm 'bottom'cm 'right'cm 'top'cm,clip]{myfigure.pdf}` will do the trick. Any dimension is allowed, but this is a bit tricky, to get right. I suggest an `\fbox{}` around the figure, if there is white around it in the input file.

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics` with `trim` and `clip` options.

Comment: a non-TeX solution is also to open the page with the graphic with a vector graphics editor such as inkscape. you can then cut and paste the graphics into another inkscape document and export that as pdf. Be careful that if the graphic in question has text in it, you should have the font installed on your system for them to display properly. I have done that numerous times to get vector version of funders logo for project reports or presentations.

Comment: See [How to extract images from a PDF in their original format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14522380)